# Is it legal to use the game mechanics of risk if I don't use their name?

Tags: game-mechanics, copyright

I'm currently developing an idea for a conquest-style board game similar to Risk. I was wondering if I would be legally entitles to use some game mechanics that appear in that game so long as I don't use Risk's title or logo or anything.

Comment: This is an important question that people clearly don't know the real answer to. Whereas the linked question is about games in general this one is about the age old classic, RISK, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: People *do* know the answer to this in general; it's answered in the linked duplicate. We don't need one of these questions for every game in the world, and we're not qualified (or interested in) cataloguing the specific legal minefields surrounding individual games in any event.

Comment: Really it should be moved to law or patents stackexchange, where the folks are much better versed in this sort of stuff, but in general you cannot market the exact same game rules with a different "skin". If you like certain elements from another game use them, but modify them.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

Game mechanics cannot be copyrighted, so using the Risk gameplay ideas should not be a problem. Obviously, you can't use the *name* Risk because that is trademarked.

That being said, I am not a lawyer. You should avoid copying exact rules or procedures from Risk as you risk (pun intended) running afoul of copyright issues.

Comment: You should be aware though that sometimes game mechanics *can* be patented. See [Can game mechanics be patented?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/210/can-game-mechanics-be-patented) on the patents exchange site.

Comment: @Octopus The link you point to says _"Hasbro dropped their lawsuit against the makers of Scrabulous after they agreed to change the name and the rules of the game, by increasing the number of letter tiles that each player receives from 7 to 8."_. Copying _all_ the game mechanics is a thing, _using some game mechanics_ is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. There is no harm to use game-mechanics of any one. Even a good mechanics may become a complete [genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre) on which world can run after for at least 6 month :)

For examples you may have a look on [ZigZag](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=zigzag&c=apps&hl=en), [Temple Run or Subway Surfers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=endless%20run&c=apps&hl=en), [Air Hockey](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=air%20hockey&c=apps&hl=en) and so on...

So in short, **YES** you can.

Comment: The question was about Risk(TM).

Comment: I'm not the representative of Risk. My answer is general.